# Get continous progress on upload to AWS/Digital Ocean Spaces using Javascript SDK V3 from browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, digital-ocean-spaces

I scoured the web looking for an answer to this (I would think) common use case of uploading a file from the client to an S3 bucket. In this case I am using Digital Ocean Spaces, but I believe they use the same API.

Sample code provided by DO (https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/spaces-api/) :

```
// Step 1: Import the S3Client object and all necessary SDK commands.
import { PutObjectCommand, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';


// Step 2: The s3Client function validates your request and directs it to your Space's specified endpoint using the AWS SDK.
const s3Client = new S3Client({
    endpoint: "https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com", // Find your endpoint in the control panel, under Settings. Prepend "https://".
    forcePathStyle: false, // Configures to use subdomain/virtual calling format.
    region: "us-east-1", // Must be "us-east-1" when creating new Spaces. Otherwise, use the region in your endpoint (e.g. nyc3).
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: "C58A976M583E23R1O00N", // Access key pair. You can create access key pairs using the control panel or API.
      secretAccessKey: process.env.SPACES_SECRET // Secret access key defined through an environment variable.
    }
});


// Step 3: Define the parameters for the object you want to upload.
const params = {
  Bucket: "example-space", // The path to the directory you want to upload the object to, starting with your Space name.
  Key: "folder-path/hello-world.txt", // Object key, referenced whenever you want to access this file later.
  Body: "Hello, World!", // The object's contents. This variable is an object, not a string.
  ACL: "private", // Defines ACL permissions, such as private or public.
  Metadata: { // Defines metadata tags.
    "x-amz-meta-my-key": "your-value"
  }
};


// Step 4: Define a function that uploads your object using SDK's PutObjectCommand object and catches any errors.
const uploadObject = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(params));
    console.log(
      "Successfully uploaded object: " +
        params.Bucket +
        "/" +
        params.Key
    );
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }
};


// Step 5: Call the uploadObject function.
uploadObject();
```

This code works fine once all variables configured and CORS is setup in the DO Control Panel. However, I could not find a way to get updates on the upload progress. I tried most everything, even had a decent back and forth with ChatGPT without success. Finally I found that you can substitute the default requesthandler of the S3Client. You do this by importing `import { XhrHttpHandler } from "@aws-sdk/xhr-http-handler";` and adding an event listener for the UPLOAD_PROGRESS event like this:

```
const handler = new XhrHttpHandler({});

handler.on(XhrHttpHandler.EVENTS.UPLOAD_PROGRESS, (xhr) => {
  // a new XMLHttpRequest is created for each command sent.
  // this is immediately after instantiation.
  // The xhr object has all the needed parts to calculate progress of the upload
  console.log(xhr)
});
```

Then add the handler to the S3Client like this:

```
const s3Client = new S3Client({
    endpoint: "https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com", // Find your endpoint in the control panel, under Settings. Prepend "https://".
    forcePathStyle: false, // Configures to use subdomain/virtual calling format.
    region: "us-east-1", // Must be "us-east-1" when creating new Spaces. Otherwise, use the region in your endpoint (e.g. nyc3).
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: "C58A976M583E23R1O00N", // Access key pair. You can create access key pairs using the control panel or API.
      secretAccessKey: process.env.SPACES_SECRET // Secret access key defined through an environment variable.
    },requestHandler: handler,

});
```

That's it! So the full code will be:

```
// Step 1: Import the S3Client object and all necessary SDK commands.
import { PutObjectCommand, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { XhrHttpHandler } from "@aws-sdk/xhr-http-handler";

const handler = new XhrHttpHandler({});

handler.on(XhrHttpHandler.EVENTS.UPLOAD_PROGRESS, (xhr) => {
  // a new XMLHttpRequest is created for each command sent.
  // this is immediately after instantiation.
  // The xhr object has all the needed parts to calculate progress of the upload
  console.log(xhr)
});

// Step 2: The s3Client function validates your request and directs it to your Space's specified endpoint using the AWS SDK.
const s3Client = new S3Client({
    endpoint: "https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com", // Find your endpoint in the control panel, under Settings. Prepend "https://".
    forcePathStyle: false, // Configures to use subdomain/virtual calling format.
    region: "us-east-1", // Must be "us-east-1" when creating new Spaces. Otherwise, use the region in your endpoint (e.g. nyc3).
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: "C58A976M583E23R1O00N", // Access key pair. You can create access key pairs using the control panel or API.
      secretAccessKey: process.env.SPACES_SECRET // Secret access key defined through an environment variable.
    },requestHandler: handler,
});


// Step 3: Define the parameters for the object you want to upload.
const params = {
  Bucket: "example-space", // The path to the directory you want to upload the object to, starting with your Space name.
  Key: "folder-path/hello-world.txt", // Object key, referenced whenever you want to access this file later.
  Body: "Hello, World!", // The object's contents. This variable is an object, not a string.
  ACL: "private", // Defines ACL permissions, such as private or public.
  Metadata: { // Defines metadata tags.
    "x-amz-meta-my-key": "your-value"
  }
};


// Step 4: Define a function that uploads your object using SDK's PutObjectCommand object and catches any errors.
const uploadObject = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(params));
    console.log(
      "Successfully uploaded object: " +
        params.Bucket +
        "/" +
        params.Key
    );
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }
};


// Step 5: Call the uploadObject function.
uploadObject();
```

Hopefully this helps some other frustrated soul like myself.